# Insert og:image in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I have the following hook for facebook's `og:image` tag.

In my template file:

```
<?php do_action('wp_head', $mypost) ?>
```

In my functions file:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'add_fb_og');
function add_fb_og($mypost) {
  if (isset($mypost["wpcf-bgleft"][0])) {
    echo '<meta property="og:image" content="'.$mypost["wpcf-bgleft"][0].'" />';
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to pass the background image of a custom field to `wp_head` so that it will output `<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/mybackgroundimage.jpg" />` for facebook's consumption.

While the output is there, facebook is not picking up the `og:image` tag.
I get the warning while using it's debug tool:

> The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

I could see the `og:image` tag in source view, so I think the head was processed before it got to the `do_action` in the template file.

How can I insert a `og:image` based on a custom field then?

I'm also using the [WordPress SEO by Yoast](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) plugin if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found out how to do it.

1. Don't call `do_action('wp_head')` in the templates section.
2. In the functions.php, do:

   ```
   add_action('wpseo_head', 'add_fb_og');
   function add_fb_og($mypost) {
     global $post;

     $mypost = get_post_custom($offid);
     if (isset($mypost["wpcf-bgleft"][0])) {
       echo '<meta property="og:image" content="'.$mypost["wpcf-bgleft"][0].'" />';
     }
   }
   ```

Note I'm using Yoast SEO's hook and calling `global $post` to get the post data, so I don't have to pass any parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress SEO by yoast also uses facebook opengraphs. So it might be interfaring try disabling it. but if you can view the tag placed correctly and in the right place. Then the problem might be in some other end.

Comment: Disabling doesn't help either. I think the problem is me calling `do_action('wp_head', $mypost)` in the template. The head might already be rendered before it inserts the `og:image` and facebook fails to pick that up. So how can I pass the image url into `wp_head` without a parameter?

Comment: I found that SEO by Yoast doesn't help with FB images. It lets you set a default but I want to override the image that's shared completely.